# Monaco Editor: Update Cursor position on text inserted

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

I'm adding some text to the Monaco editor using a button outside it (i.e. "hello world") and then I'm trying to set the cursor position to the next line.

I tried using the "setPosition({column:x, lineNumber:y})" function from the editor, but it doesn't work.

This is how I'm implementing it:

```
insertInPosition(textToInsert:string, cursorPosition:any){
    this.editorInstance.setPosition(cursorPosition);
    var allInstructions = this.instructionSet.split("\n")
    allInstructions.splice(cursorPosition.lineNumber - 1, 0, textToInsert);
    allInstructions.splice(cursorPosition.lineNumber, 1);
    allInstructions = allInstructions.join("\n");
    this.editorInstance.setPosition(cursorPosition);
}
```

I expect to see the cursor in the line and column defined by cursorPosition, but I actually see that the cursor points to line 1 and column 1 (At the top of the editor).

I also tried to use the same api `editor.setPosition()` inside the `onDidChangeModelContent()` method, but it doesn't works. And when I print in console the `editor.getPosition()` I receive the correct positions.

Any idea on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

```
this.editor?.trigger('keyboard', 'type', {text: 'value'});
this.editor?.focus();
const position: any  = this.editor?.getPosition();
this.editor?.setPosition(position);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Some monaco editor events (including `onDidChangeModelContent()`), change cursor position after executing. I took this information [from here](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1397?ref=https://githubhelp.com#issuecomment-488278630).

To prevent it from happening, you can do something like this:

```js
var overridenPosition = null;

editor.onDidChangeModelContent(e => {
    if (/* your condition here */) {
        // your logic here
        overridenPosition = { lineNumber: 4, column: 2 }; // put your value here
    }
});

editor.onDidChangeCursorPosition(e => {
    if (overridenPosition != null) {
        editor.setPosition(overridenPosition);
        overridenPosition = null;
    }
});
```